# KeyError: 0 on an api request

Tags: python, api, keyerror

I'm running an api request on google places and am running into issues with a keyerror 0. I'm not sure where to go from there. 
Here is my code:

```
cities = df1['name']
parameters = f"radius=5000&type=hotel"
key  = g_key
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/nearbysearch/json?location="

for city in range(len(cities)):
    rr = requests.get(url + str(cities[city]) + parameters + "&key=" + key)
    responses.append(rr.json())
```

Comment: `parameters = f"radius=5000&type=hotel"` what is the f doing in there?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over the range of the number of cities and reading the city at different indexes try using `for...in` python loop as follows:

```
for city in cities:
    r = requests.get(f"{url}{city}&parameters&key={key}")
    responses.append(r.json())
```

This might prevent you from encountering the KeyError when trying to read the value at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `keyerror 0` occurs because at this line

```
for city in range(len(cities)):
    rr = requests.get(url + str(cities[city]) + parameters + "&key=" + key)  # <----this line
    responses.append(rr.json())
```

you are trying to access `cities` values as if `cities` were a list, that is, by passing it numeric arguments, rather than by passing it key arguments (strings), which is (one of) the correct way to access dictionaries values.

As suggested by N. Solomon, you should iterate through `cities` keys, in this way the counter variable is directly assigned the key (string) you need to pass to the `cities` dictionary to get its values.